# is it safe to insert a usb-c headset inside a usb-c charging input

Tags: usb-3.1-type-c

I recently bought the MSI prestige 15 and I have trouble figuring out if is it safe to insert a usb-c headset inside a usb-c charging input.

[type c input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtQ6e.jpg)

As you can see in the picture above it seems like I have 2 charging type c ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly safe.  The USB charge controller and the headset will negotiate power with each other, allowing the headset to be properly powered.  However, this means no data will be able to be transferred.

Obviously, if it *wasnt* safe, there would be a lot of people plugging in devices into the port with possible bad consequences.  This would be a poor design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Any USB-C device is safe to plug into any USB-C receptacle. Whether or not it will work is another question, but you do not risk damaging the device or the laptop.

The little plug() indicator above the ports indicate that you can plug your laptop charger into them to charge the laptop itself.

The little lightning bolt (⚡) to the right of each port indicates that these are also Thunderbolt ports as well.